# Should I reword this question to try get it reopened?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400697/how-to-redirect-domainname-com-index-html-innerpage-to-domainname-com-innerpage) question was put on hold because it wasn't clear what they were asking. I had an idea what they wanted so I asked if my assumption was correct (I asked it before it was put on hold). They have since then replied and my assumption is correct.

I tried to edit the post to make it clear what they were asking and flagged the question to be reopened, but [the edit was declined](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4364778). 
Should I have tried to reworded the question and reopen it?

Comment: Man, that question is a mess, but your edit took away too much. Also "reworded the question for clarification" is a generic edit summary likely to lead to rejection of such a big change. "Clarified using information from comments" would be more likely to lead to approval. But focus less on **removing** and more on **adding** to make things clearer.

Answer (score 8):

You were right to try to edit it. However, when editing a question to get it re-opened (or to block closure) you'll want to always **make the question the best possible question you can** - don't *just* edit to correct a few problems. In this case, you'll want to,

- Include the actual code in the question as a code block, *not* an image.
- Make sure all spelling, capitalization, punctuation and grammar issues are corrected.

...and also make sure the edit summary includes a clear description of where the information you're introducing was obtained. So instead of writing "Reworded the question for clarification" you could write, "Reworded question to reflect asker's clarifications from the comment thread".